# Get characters before underscore and separated by comma from a string in SQL Server 2008

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I tried this query

```
 DECLARE @AdvancedSearchSelectedDropdownName TABLE (
    SelectedIds VARCHAR(2048),
    AdvanceSearchOptionTypeId INT
)

INSERT INTO @AdvancedSearchSelectedDropdownName
VALUES ('4_0,5_1,6_2,7_3', 23),
       ('62_3', 21), ('2_4', 23)

DECLARE @selectedIds VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @selectedIds +=
    CASE WHEN SelectedIds IS NULL
            THEN  @selectedIds  +  ISNULL(SelectedIds + ',', '')
         WHEN SelectedIds IS NOT NULL
            THEN  SUBSTRING(SelectedIds, 0, CHARINDEX('_', SelectedIds, 0)) + ','
    END
   FROM @AdvancedSearchSelectedDropdownName WHERE advanceSearchOptionTypeId = 23

SELECT @selectedIds
```

Current output: 4,2

Required output: 4,5,6,7,2

We may have n number of comma separated values in the `SelectedIds` column.

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Answer (score 5):

You might go this route:

```
WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT * 
          ,CAST('<x><y>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(SelectedIds,'_','</y><y>'),',','</y></x><x><y>') + '</y></x>' AS XML)  SplittedToXml
    FROM @AdvancedSearchSelectedDropdownName
)
SELECT *
FROM Casted;
```

This will return your data in this form:

```
<x>
  <y>4</y>
  <y>0</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>5</y>
  <y>1</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>6</y>
  <y>2</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>7</y>
  <y>3</y>
</x>
```

Now we can grab all the x and just the first y:

```
WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT * 
          ,CAST('<x><y>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(SelectedIds,'_','</y><y>'),',','</y></x><x><y>') + '</y></x>' AS XML)  SplittedToXml
    FROM @AdvancedSearchSelectedDropdownName
)
SELECT Casted.AdvanceSearchOptionTypeId AS TypeId
      ,x.value('y[1]/text()[1]','int') AS IdValue
FROM Casted
CROSS APPLY SplittedToXml.nodes('/x') A(x);
```

The result:

```
TypeId  IdValue
23      4
23      5
23      6
23      7
21      62
23      2
```

### Hint: Do not store comma delimited values!

It is a very bad idea to store your data in this format. You can use a generic format like my XML to store this or a structure of related side tables. But such construction tend to turn out as a real pain in the neck...

Comment: Digging the nested XML in one pass

Comment: @JohnCappelletti yeah, that's cool. I found this once shredding a multi-line csv. Used the line breaks and the semicolon in one single pass and got the whole file as xml.

Answer (score 3):

After a little re-think.  Perhaps something a little more straightforward.

Now, if you have a limited number of `_N`

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
Select *
      ,RN = Row_Number() over(Order by (Select NULL))
    From  @AdvancedSearchSelectedDropdownName A
)
Select AdvanceSearchOptionTypeId
      ,IDs = replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             replace(
             stuff((Select ',' +SelectedIds From cte Where AdvanceSearchOptionTypeId=A.AdvanceSearchOptionTypeId Order by RN For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
             ,'_0','')
             ,'_1','')
             ,'_2','')
             ,'_3','')
             ,'_4','')
 From  cte A
 Group By AdvanceSearchOptionTypeId
```

**Returns**

```
AdvanceSearchOptionTypeId   IDs
21                          62
23                          4,5,6,7,2
```

Answer (score 2):

If interested in a helper function.

Tired of extracting strings (left, right, charindex, patindex, ...) I modified s split/parse function to accept TWO non-like delimiters.  In this case a `,` and `_`.

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
    Select A.AdvanceSearchOptionTypeId
          ,B.*
          ,RN = Row_Number() over(Order by (Select NULL))
     From  @AdvancedSearchSelectedDropdownName A
     Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](','+A.SelectedIds,',','_') B
)
Select AdvanceSearchOptionTypeId
      ,IDs = stuff((Select ',' +RetVal From cte Where AdvanceSearchOptionTypeId=A.AdvanceSearchOptionTypeId Order by RN,RetVal For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
 From cte A
 Group By AdvanceSearchOptionTypeId
```

**Returns**

```
AdvanceSearchOptionTypeId   IDs
21                          62
23                          4,5,6,7,2
```

**The TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Disclaimer.As per first Normal form, you should not store multiple values in a single cell. I would suggest you to avoid storing this way.

Still the approach would be: Create a UDF function which separates comma separated list into a table valued variable. Below code I have not tested. but, it gives idea on how to approach this problem.

[Refer to CSV to table approaches](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amitjet/2009/12/11/convert-comma-separated-string-to-table-4-different-approaches/)

```
Declare @selectedIds varchar(max) = '';
SET @selectedIds = SELECT STUFF
   (SELECT ','+ (SUBSTRING(c.value, 0, CHARINDEX('_', c.value, 0)) 
   FROM @AdvancedSearchSelectedDropdownName AS tv 
   CROSS APPLY dbo.udfForCSVToList(SelectedIds) AS c
   WHERE advanceSearchOptionTypeId = 23
   FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'');
SELECT @selectedIds
```

Comment: The heavy work is the tokenizer... Btw. this `SELECT @selectedIds += ...` is called *quirky update* and is not recommended to concatenate a string. There might be unexpected results... Better use `FOR XML PATH('')` and - starting with v2016 - there is `STRING_AGG()`...